# Returning a varchar value from a coalesced int calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014-express

I'm a newbie learning my way around T-SQL using the `AdventureWorks2012` database. I'm using SQL Server 2014, though a solution that would also work with 2008 would be great. I've been given the below exercise:

> *Write a query using the Sales.SpecialOffer table. Display the difference between the MinQty and MaxQty columns along with the SpecialOfferID and Description columns.*

Thing is, `MaxQty` allows for null values, so I'm trying to come up with a real world solution for an output that doesn't involve leaving nulls in there.  However, when I try to use coalesce to return 'No Max' (yes, I get that I could just leave NULL in there but I'm trying to see if I can figure this out), I get the message that the `varchar` value 'No Max' couldn't be converted to data type `int`. I'm assuming this is because `MaxQty - MinQty` as an `int` takes precedence?

```
select 
    specialofferid
    , description
    , coalesce((maxqty - minqty),'No Max') 'Qty_Difference'
from 
    sales.specialoffer;
```

Error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 135
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'No max' to data type int.

I thought about just returning a nonsense integer (0 or a negative) but that doesn't seem perfect - if return 0 I'm obscuring situations where the result is actually zero, etc.

Thoughts?

Comment: `varchar value 'Null value'`? where would maxqty or minqty be converted to a string?

Comment: @MarcB: `select coalesce(cast(null as int),'a');` -> `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'a' to data type int.`

Comment: @Andomar: yeah, but there's no `'Null value'` in OP's query...

Comment: Sorry, I copied a previous error message, I updated it.

Comment: Make sure the types are consistent: `coalesce(cast(maxqty - minqty as varchar), 'No Max')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to make sure that all the parameters of the `COALESCE` function call have consistent data types.  Because you can't get around the fact `No Max` is a string, then you have to make sure that the `maxqty - minqty` part is also treated as a string by casting the expression.

```
select specialofferid
, description
, coalesce(cast(maxqty - minqty as varchar),'No Max') 'Qty_Difference'
from sales.specialoffer;
```

**EDIT: A few more details on the cause of the error**

Without the explicit cast, the reason why the `COALESCE` function attempts to convert the `No Max` string to an `int` can be explained by the following [documented rule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx):

> Data type determination of the resulting expression is different. ISNULL uses the data type of the first parameter, COALESCE follows the CASE expression rules and **returns the data type of value with the highest precedence.**

And if you check the precedence of the different types, as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx), then you will see that `int` has higher precedence than `varchar`.

So as soon as you have a mix of data types in the call to `COALESCE`, SQL Server will try to convert all mismatching parameters to the data type with highest precedence, in this case `int`.  To override that default behavior, explicit type casting is required.

Comment: This. A column should only have one type.

Comment: Ahhhh ok.  So it isn't that maxqty - minqty  was an int taking precedence over the string, it's that the column was going to have int in some case and varchar in others.  Very useful, didn't even think of that.  Thanks!

Comment: I imagine the first type that happened to result from the query would be interpreted as 'the' type for the generated column.

Comment: @underscore_d and OP: The reason why the error happens is clearly documented. I edited my answer to include the relevant information.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a case statement to so you can do stuff you want.

```
select specialofferid
, description
, CASE 
     WHEN  maxqty is null THEN 'No Max'
     ELSE (maxqty - minqty) 'Qty_Difference'
  END
from sales.specialoffer;
```

Comment: I can't get that to work, I get the error:

    The isnull function requires 2 argument(s).

When I modify it to isnull(maxqty,'') I get:

    An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'THEN'

Comment: I should say I previously tried case and got the same error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'No Max' to data type int.".  I did mine a little differently:

'Qty_Different' = 
 case when maxqty is null then 'No Max'
 when maxqty is not null then (maxqty - minqty)
 end

Comment: @JulianDrago I haven't used isnull for a while.  made a change.

Comment: Why exactly would you say `when -1 = isnull(column, -1)` rather than the dedicated syntax `when column is null`? Not to mention what I said above: a column should only have one type. Your query will create two, if it works at all.

Comment: @underscore_d thanks, that is actually what I wanted, was thinking to much other dbs..

Comment: @JulianDrago, not that it is relevant to `isnull`, but SQL Server does not perform explicit evaluation of boolean expressions, so you have to say `when 1 = booleanExpression`, etc.

Comment: Errors out as written